# How is this text edit control done?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010, when you edit the text of a label component a popup appears showing the entire text in a multiline format. Does anyone know how this popup multiline text editing box is done or called? I'd like to do this in a C# program I'm creating.

A screenshot can be found [here](http://www.pkhlineworks.ca/screenshot.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a ToolTip - documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

For editing see [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/449554-Text-Box-Style-Multiline-Property-Grid-Text) article that uses the [MultiLineStringEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.multilinestringeditor.aspx).

Comment: Isn't a ToolTip a static message? The screenshot shows a multi-line edit box for a property-line that does not fit into the window (you can see the active cursor at the end of the text).

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the multiline text editor in the property sheet, this is part of the property grid and isn't standalone IFAIK.